# Adding a security in soap header not responding anything

Tags: java, soap, soapui

I am trying to access a soap service in soapui. I have following request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:service.com:dc:testservice">
 <soapenv:Header>
 </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:IsUserAvailable>
         <urn:appId>CoolCompany</urn:appId>
         <urn:userId>test</urn:userId>
         <urn:orgId>coolOrg</urn:orgId>
      </urn:IsUserAvailable>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The above request is returning result but as soon as I add security in the header soapui is showing following

```
HTTP/1.1 400 
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 09 Mar 2022 21:57:42 GMT
Connection: close
```

what I added to the header section is following

```
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd>
<o:UsernameToken u:Id="12345">
<o:Username>admin</o:Username>
<o:Password>SomePassword</o:Password>
</o:UsernameToken>
</o:Security>
```

OR

```
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd>
</o:Security>
```

In both the above cases soapui is not showing anything except the

> Connection: close

. Can anyone point out where I have to change my request.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked with the service provider?

Comment: What to check with service provider?

Comment: Hi, Rao has a point.  What you're doing there is passing your credentials in clear text.  You need to ask the provider what authentication they're using.  Then you can create the authorisation within SoapUI, but not how you've added it in.  See https://www.soapui.org/docs/oauth2/oauth2-authorization/?query=Authentication